# Replace default image with random image from same folder

Tags: php, image, random

I'm just learning php and am stuck on a basic problem. I'd like my site to display one of ten random images (1.png ... 10.png) if a user doesn't choose an image. Currently it just displays a single image by default. There is a thumbnail and full size version of this image.

I've found the file where this is controlled is:

```
<?php
class Sabai_Helper_NoImageUrl extends Sabai_Helper
{
    public function help(Sabai $application, $small = false)
    {       
        $file = $small ? 'no_image_small.png' : 'no_image.png';
        return $application->getPlatform()->getAssetsUrl() . '/images/' . $file;
    }
}
```

I've tried to replace 'no_image_small.png' with the names of my images typed out in quotes ('1.png', '2.png',...). Other answers I've seen on stackoverflow are a little too advanced for me to apply as I don't know where to add arrays for both the 'no_image_small.png' and 'no_image.png'.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what framework you are using, what classes are extended, but try this:

```
class Sabai_Helper_NoImageUrl extends Sabai_Helper
{
    public function help(Sabai $application, $small = false)
    {       
        $random = rand(1, 10);
        $file = $small ? $random.'_small.png' : $random.'.png';
        return $application->getPlatform()->getAssetsUrl() . '/images/' . $file;
    }
}
```

This assumes, that the images "1.png".."10.png" and "1_small.png".."10_small.png" are located in the same directory, where no_image_small.png and no_image.png are stored.

For example:

```
$random = rand(1, 10); // generating random number and saving to $random variable
echo $random.'.png';   // concatenating random number to .png extension
```

Outputs:

```
8.png
```

or any other from 1 to 10

This should set $file variable with the correct image.

Reference: [rand](http://php.net/rand)

Comment: That worked Dmytro! This answer has been really helpful in giving some new areas to explore php. Thank you

Comment: ok done. took me a while to find the accepted button... but think it's officially accepted now.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using php** [rand()](http://www.php.net/rand)

You can use `rand(1,10)` this means echo out a random numbers from 1 to 10.

like for example: echo rand(1,10)."jpg";